# How do I get a facebook page access token without iterating the accounts list?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook [documents how to get a page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) by having you call the Graph API to get a list of all your fb accounts. This is done by making a GET request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

However this returns a *list* of accounts:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "PAGE_TITLE", 
      "access_token": "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "category": "PAGE_CATEGORY", 
      "id": "PAGE_ID"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "PAGE_TITLE", 
      "access_token": "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "category": "PAGE_CATEGORY", 
      "id": "PAGE_ID"
    }, 
    ...
 ]
}
```

I have the fb id of the page I want. Rather than walk the list looking for a matching id, isn't there a Graph API call to directly fetch the block of data? My end goal is to retrieve the page access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, just change the PAGE_ID and USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN